# Measurement Protocol with uid but without cid not received in GA

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a booking system where a booking can be made: 
  1. immediately by a customer, or 
  2. on their behalf by a customer service agent.

For 1, I've had success POSTing an event hit to the Measurement Protocol with a [`cid`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) and our [`uid`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) for a "purchase". Initially without the `cid`, it wasn't working despite the docs saying only one of `uid` **or** `cid` are required.

For 2, which isn't customer initiated, when I don't pass a `cid` nothing comes through to GA (neither the real-time dashboard or the ecomm report).

Here's the hit for option 1, broken in to lines for easier viewing:

```
t=event
&v=1
&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-2
&ec=Ecommerce
&ea=Purchase
&ti=176410
&ta=Some+Affiliation
&pa=purchase
&tr=123.45
&pr1id=Repair367
&pr1nm=Something+Replacement
&pr1pr=123.45
&pr1qt=1
&pr1ca=Repair%2FInspection
&pr1ps=1
&cd3=None
&ni=1
&uid=469585
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so it turns out this is the case:

- If using cid, your hit will appear in your property's standard view's real-time Event screen (immediately) and ecomm Sales Performance screen (~10mins later for me)
- If using uid *and no cid*, your hit will appear ONLY in those screens under your property's UserID view.

I'd been looking in the standard view and nothing was appearing as soon as I swapped over to a uid-only hit when it was customer service initiated. So although the docs say only one of either `uid` or `cid` are required, it should mention it has a significant affect on where the data is viewable in GA.

Sigh.